# open file in system default application in C

Tags: c, ubuntu, gtk3

I'm writing a simple http program which downloads a file,maybe .html, .jpg or any others
and how can i open the file using the system default application in C code
This program is on ubuntu12.10 and based on gtk3.x
sorry for my English and thanks in advance.

Comment: yeah but what is you question ?

Comment: Unix doesn't have "default applications". This is a feature of some file managers, not Unix in general.

Comment: So maybe GNOME api can help?

Comment: You can identify many file types using the unix file command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that

```
GFile *g_file_new_for_path(const gchar *path);

GAppInfo *g_file_query_default_handler(GFile *file,GCancellable *cancellable,GError **error);

gboolean g_app_info_launch(GAppInfo *appinfo,GList *files,GAppLaunchContext *launch_context,GError **error);
```

Create a GFile and get its default handler,then launch it
`g_app_info_launch` will return TRUE if success